# How to Check all checkboxes

Tags: python-3.x, google-chrome, checkbox, selenium-chromedriver, findelement

I need to sellect all checkboxes in webpage using python 3.8 and  chromedrive.

This function is working in javascript, i want the same code in python

```
< script type = "text/javascript" >
    function selects() {
        var ele = document.getElementsByName('chk');
        for (var i = 0; i < ele.length; i++) {
            if (ele[i].type == 'checkbox')
                ele[i].checked = true;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass any JS code to selenium `driver`, for example:

```
script = '''
var ele = document.getElementsByName('chk');
for (var i = 0; i < ele.length; i++) {
    if (ele[i].type == 'checkbox')
        ele[i].checked = true;
}'''

diver.get("https://somedomain.com/")
driver.execute_script(script)
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks william wu, your answer helped!
find_element_by_* commands are deprecated in python 3.7+
I did some modifications

```
xPath = "//input[@type='checkbox']"
elems = driver.find_elements("xpath", xPath)
for elem in elems:
    if elem.tag_name == "input" and elem.get_attribute("type") == "checkbox":
        elem.click()
```

This code worked for me and thanks again.